# Twilio Voice: How to use javascript client sdk in PHP application?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have a PHP application for Twilio Voice browser calls. I am using CDN version of the twilio client js.

Twilio recommends to use npm version for the client SDK. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-client.js#readme

I am not sure how to use the npm version. My application is hosted in a shared hosting.

Looking for guidance.

Comment: npm ultimately just downloads a bunch of files into a folder. You just need to do that locally and deploy the files to your server.

Comment: It downloads over 120MB of files. Not sure we need all of them.